# Google app engine deployment failing: [9] An internal error occurred [...] You must install or update .NET to run this application

Tags: c#, .net, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a .NET 7 app on app engine, but I get the following error :

#### Error

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-12-01T04:02:39.227Z143518.vt
.1: You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /app/Cyclee.API.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

The following frameworks were found:
  7.0.0 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

If I understand well, it seems like the server is missing the right dotnet version to run the app. Those are my app.yaml and Dockerfile:

#### app.yaml

```yaml
runtime: custom
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
  ConnectionStrings__SqlDatabase:
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Cyclee.API/Cyclee.API.csproj", "Cyclee.API/"]
COPY ["Cyclee.API.Domain/Cyclee.API.Domain.csproj", "Cyclee.API.Domain/"]
COPY ["Cyclee.API.Infrastructure/Cyclee.API.Infrastructure.csproj", "Cyclee.API.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Cyclee.API/Cyclee.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Cyclee.API"
RUN dotnet build "Cyclee.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Cyclee.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Cyclee.API.dll"]
```

Comment: What does your csproj file look like? My guess is that you're targeting .NET 6...

Comment: Can you check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-discovery/troubleshoot-app-launch?pivots=os-windows#required-framework-not-found)?

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, it was as simple as that. I already had retargeted the solution but it didn't affect the individual projects as I would have expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Jon Skeet, I simply needed to retarget the projects from .NET 6 to .NET 7.